# NetLogo: Refer to current item in 'foreach'

Tags: foreach, netlogo

Let's say I have

```
globals [x]
patches-own [number]

to set.x
  set x list 3 8
end

to set.number
  ask patches [
    set number random 10
  ]
end
```

Let's say now I want each patch with `number` = 3 or `number` = 8 to change `number` to 0.

I want to do it using `foreach`, but I am not understanding how I can use `foreach` to iterate through `x` **and**, while that happens, refer to the current value being used from `x`.

Something like

```
to bring.to.zero
  foreach x ask patches with [number = *the current value from x*]
    [set number 0]
  ]
end
```

I am very aware this last bit of code is not valid both in its syntax and in the fact that I don't know how to express that passage between asterisks; I cannot wrap my head around how to make it work.
Perhaps I just do not use NetLogo enough, but the description of `foreach` from the NetLogo dictionary didn't help me either.

Note that I solved the specific problem with a different approach:

```
to bring.to.zero
  ask patches [
    if member? number x [set number 0]
  ]
end
```

But I am still curious as if and how it could be done with `foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where very close, the problem is that you need to use an anonymous procedure to map the current iteration to a command; this will work `foreach x [a -> ask patches with [number = a][set number 0]]`, here `a` is the current value that `foreach` read of the list `x`

Here is a little script I made, in `setup` the patches will take random colors from 0 to 9 (so `pcolor` is like a proxy of your variable numbers) and the list `x` will get populated, with `make-red` the patches with `pcolor` in `x` will turn red, finally `blue-the-red` will make all the non-red patches blue by turning a `agentset` into a `list` and iterating it with `foreach`.

```
globals [x]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [set pcolor random 10]
  set x list 3 8
end

to make-red
  foreach x [ a -> ask patches with [pcolor = a] [set pcolor red] ]
end

to blue-the-red
  ; ask every non-red patch to change its color to blue
  ; also helps to illustrate how an agent-set becomes a list
  foreach [self] of patches with [pcolor != red] [a -> ask a [set pcolor blue] ]
end
```